# PYTHON 2.7 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'

Tags: python, opencv

i'm using this code to record video with a PS3 camera *the code is in spanish by the way that's why i wrote "camara" and not "camera".

i'm using Python 2.7 and opencv 3.4.0.12, i'm assuming that the problem is the version of opencv but i don't think so BUT HONESTLY AT THIS POINT I DON'T KNOW WHAT'S RIGHT OR WRONG, PLEASE HELP.

When i run it i get this errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\carls\OneDrive\Documentos\VIDEO CAMARA PS3.py", line 31, in
>   
>       camara1()   File "C:\Users\carls\OneDrive\Documentos\VIDEO CAMARA PS3.py", line 9, in camara1
>       fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*"XVID") AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'

Also when i run the code instead of recording in the PS3 camera, the camera from my laptop turns on.

## THIS IS PART OF THE CODE TOO, SORRY!

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

import random

import time

def camara1():

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*"XVID")

    size1 = (int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) )
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, size1)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
             ret, frame = cap.read()
             if ret==True:
                 frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

                 out.write(frame)

                 cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
                 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                     break
             else:
                 break
    #Release everything if job is finished
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

camara1() #THIS IS IN THE CODE TOO, SORRY. THIS IS THE LAST CODE LINE
```

Comment: Why did you write that `cv2.cv`, and why do you expect it to work? Nothing in the tutorial or the docs for current or 3.4.0 has anything like that.

Comment: For example, see [Saving a Video](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html?highlight=fourcc#saving-a-video) in the official tutorial.

Comment: i corrected my code and it works! the only problem is that is upside down.

Comment: That sounds like a completely new problem that you should create a new question for (after searching and trying to debug it as far as you can yourself, of course).

Comment: now it's working perfectly. I'm trying to do the same thing but now on Raspberry Pi 3 using the same Python version but, i get ImportError: No module named cv2. I installed opencv 3 and numpy. I'm guessing that maybe the error comes from the installation for opencv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

works for me.

Opencv version 3.x supports cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc,  whereas cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC was supported by 2.4.x.